# Is there a way to add logic operand to the search parameter?

Tags: add-on, ee2, templates, channel-entries

I am looking for a way to isolate entries based on a  {event_time_start} and {event_time_end} custom field. For instance the first one contains 930 as a value and the second one 1200 meaning the event start at 9:30 and ends à 12:00.

I am trying to display which event is on right now by doing something like :

**search:event_time_start="<930" search:event_time_end=">1200"**

But this outputs sweet nothing. I had a look at [this entry about the search param](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#search-field-name) and I see there is no support for < and > but I was wondering if an extension / add-on / something would support add this feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would check out [Low Search](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search), you should be able to search by range on a custom field. [Solspace's Super Search](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/super_search/) is another option, but it's a bit pricier.

Comment: I was half hoping for a solution that would replace the EE mechanis so I would be able so use the search: param in other addons that support the default implementation. Guess I'll have to settle on a workaround. Thanks for pointing out Low Search.

Answer (score 1):

There is no add-on to add support for this since there is no way to hook into that particular part of the channel-module by means of an extension-hook.

There used to be a solution for EE1 made by (I believe) Mark Huot, but that required hacking the EE code directly... which is not advisable.

– Wouter

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to use a snippet that checks the search range and returns a bool. This way you can run the range through whatever query you need.